# Erro ao fazer uma formatação em python usando o comando .find

Tags: python, formatação

Estou tentando encontrar quantas vezes a letra "A" se repete em uma variável, porém não consigo encontrar o erro ao dar o comando de formatação.

```
p = str(input('Digite uma frase: ')).strip().upper() 

print(f' {(p.find('A'))}')

SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '('
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando utilizar aspas simples dentro de uma string criada com aspas simples. O resultado disso é um fechamento não intencional da string — deixando de fora a letra `A` dela — e abrindo uma nova string na sequência.

Para solucionar o problema, basta utilizas aspas duplas para criar a string, como no código abaixo:

```
print(f" {(p.find('A'))}")
```

Ademais, o método `find()` serve apenas para obter a posição de uma substring. Para contar quantas vezes uma substring aparece na string, utilize o método `count()`, dessa forma:

```
print(f" {p.count('A')}")
```